# Quadratic Inequalities: My answer is different from the ones provided.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

The problem is:

$$x^2 + 2x - 1 < 0$$

Step 1: Move the $1$ to the other side.

$$x^2 + 2x < 1$$

Step 2: Add $1$ to both sides to complete the quadratic equation.

$$x^2 + 2x + 1 < 2$$

Step 3: Factor the quadratic equation.

$$(x + 1)^2 < 2$$

Step 4:

$$(x + 1) < \pm \sqrt2$$

Step 5:

$$x_1 < 1.41 - 1 \qquad and \qquad x_2 < -1.41 - 1$$

Step 6:

$$x_1 < 0.41 \qquad and \qquad x_2 < -2.41$$

My Answer is:

$$SC: (-\infty, -2.41)$$

The possible answers are:

$$
\begin{align}
&a)\quad (-\sqrt2,\ \sqrt2)\\
&b)\quad (-\sqrt2 - 1,\ -\sqrt2 + 1)\\
&c)\quad (1 - \sqrt2,\ 1 + \sqrt2)\\
&d)\quad (-\sqrt2 - 1,\ \sqrt2 - 1)\\
&e)\quad (-2 - \sqrt2,\ 3- \sqrt2)\\
\end{align}
$$

Where did I go wrong, what could I do better?

Comment: you have to consider $|x+2|<\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $\sqrt{2} \neq 1.41$
It's just an approximation. You don't need it here, just leave $\sqrt{2}$ as it is.

Comment: The issue appears in step 5. Pick something simpler, say, $x^2 < 1$. Draw a picture. Is it really equivalent to $x<1$ or $x<-1$?

Comment: @pjs36 I got it, no its not the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this step:
$$(x + 1)^2 < 2$$
you get:
$$|x + 1| < \sqrt{2}$$
so you get
$$x + 1 < \sqrt{2}$$ 
$$x + 1 > -\sqrt{2}$$
which simplifies to:
$$x < \sqrt{2} - 1$$ 
$$x > -\sqrt{2} - 1$$
so your answer is

d) $(-\sqrt2 - 1; \sqrt2 - 1)$

You can visualize the answer with this graph:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @jh314. Where could I learn to do that kind of graphics?

Comment: I just plugged $(x+1)^2<2$ into wolfram alpha!

Answer (score 1):

for $x\geq -1$ we have $$x<\sqrt{2}-1$$ and for $x<-1$ we get $$-1-\sqrt{2}<x$$

Answer (score 1):

If the square of a number is less then $a$ then it is wrong (and meaningless) to say that that number is less that $\pm\sqrt{a}$. Instead, from $t^2<a$ it follows that $-a<t<a$. So in your case $-\sqrt2<x+1<\sqrt2$.